# Get external website's meta-description after returning success page in Django

Tags: python, django

I need to get the meta-description of an external website entered by the user. My code currently does this but it has to wait for the external website to respond. This is a problem for obvious reasons.

So what I want is: Add link to database (already does), then return success page to user and only then go get the meta-descrition, title and stuff like that from the external site and add to database.

From what I've been reading, Celery would be my best bet. However, I'm a novice and it seems a little too complicated for me yet.

One possibility I've came up with would be to make a script to run like every second and check for links on the database that are flagged or something like that. The script would check if there's a txt file present to start the job. This txt file would be created after the link is added to the database. Is this a viable option or would generate too many problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Celery *is* excellent, and the way to go for *most* background tasks. It has a learning curve, but it is well worth it if you intend to use this pattern frequently.

However, [RQ](http://python-rq.org/) (Redis Queue for Python) can be a much simpler solution (but it won't run on Windows like Celery can).

Take a look at "Getting Started" at http://python-rq.org/ to see how easy this could be for you.

Comment: Thanks for showing me this. I'd love to try it some time.

Comment: Both are well worth looking at. I'm using Celery a lot (on Windows with Microsoft's port of redis) and it is superb too.

Comment: Thank you, I'll certanly have I look at that. It seems much easier to implement. But what about the option I've given. Do you think it wouldn't work properly?

Comment: Sure, you can have a stand-alone background process that polls the database every so often looking for missing content (I wouldn't even use the file system). Having done similar things in the past, though, I recommend the RQ model, especially if you might be doing something like this more than once, because it tends to get messy.